# In Citus, how do I lock a distributed table during a COPY?

Tags: postgresql, citus

Citus does not support multi-statement transactions for data modification commands, making it impossible to use the `LOCK` command for preventing concurrent access during data migrations.

Is there any way to lock access to a table during an initial data migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Citus does prevent multi-statement transactions which contain modifications, this check apparently does not apply to the new `COPY` support. So if you are actually doing a `COPY` and not `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`, you can use `BEGIN` and `LOCK` to get the single-write semantics you desire:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK target_table IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

COPY target_table FROM '/file/on/server';
\copy target_table from '~/local/file'

COMMIT;
```

If a concurrent session attempts an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` against this table, it will block until the above transaction block commits.

Comment: When I try to do this I fall into [this](https://github.com/citusdata/citus/issues/543) problem

Comment: That only a check and `COPY` still does not use transactions. So if I decide `ROLLBACK` at your example partially migrated data will not rolled back. Does I understand right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that description is accurate. The `COPY` itself can be atomic, but we don't (presently) propagate the surrounding transaction commands to the workers.